# Checking if the following natural language to logic translations are correct

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I would like to check if the following translations from natural language to predicate logic are correct:

1.) "A white dog sees a pink panther":

D(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a white dog". S(x, y) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ sees $\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{y}$". P(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a pink panther"

Formula: $\exists x. \exists y. D(x) \land P(y) \land S(x, y)$

2.) "Werewolves only come out at full moon":

W(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a werewolf". O(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ only comes out at full moon".

Formula: $\forall x. W(x) \implies O(x)$

3.) "All birds lay eggs, and some birds eat meat":

B(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a bird". E(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ lays eggs". M(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ eats meat".

Formula: $(\forall x. B(x) \implies E(x)) \land (\exists x. B(x) \land M(x))$

Comment: All your answers are correct, well done.